# Creating buttons through iteration?

Tags: loops, button, lua, coronasdk

I've been using the Corona engine and I'm trying to create multiple buttons through a loop rather than explicitly creating each individual button. Problem is the loop only seems to be generating one button which suggests it's only iterating once.

Below is what I've got so far...

**UPDATED**

```
--> Create Level Selection:

local levelSelectionGroup = display.newGroup( );

--> Level Selected:

local function levelSelected()
    print(id);
end

--> Button Creation:

local function createLevelSelection()
    local levelsToBeMade = 30; -- Ignore these random numbers for now.
    local positionX = 1; -- Ignore again.
    local positionY = 1; -- Ignore again.

    for buttonNumber=1, levelsToBeMade do
        print(buttonNumber);

        positionX = (positionX + 10); -- Ignore again.
        positionY = (positionY + 10); -- Ignore again.

        levelButton[buttonNumber] = widget.newButton{ 
            id = buttonNumber,
            label = buttonNumber,
            default = "images/levelButton.png",
            over = "images/levelButtonPressed.png",
            width = 50,
            height = 50,
            onRelease = levelSelected
        }

        levelButton[buttonNumber].x = positionX;
        levelButton[buttonNumber].y = positionY;

        levelSelectionGroup:insert(levelButton[buttonNumber]);
    end
end
```

The console states...

```
attempt to index global 'levelButton' (a nil value)
```

Comment: A typo: `levelstToBeMade`?

Comment: Ah. Sadly that still hasn't solved the issue of it not looping.

Comment: I think you need to push/insert them into a display group.

Comment: I gave that a shot but still no success, at least it's nice to have them all grouped together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you might have a problem with your variables or your scopes. So make sure that levelsToBeMade variable and positionX and positionY variables are correct. If you are absolutely sure, this should work: ( I don't see anything wrong in your code but, for loops are more trustable I guess. )

```
for i=1, levelsToBeMade do

    print( "levelButton+1).." will be created." )

    positionX = positionX + 10; -- Ignore numbers.
    positionY = postionY + 10; -- Ignore numbers.

    levelButton[#levelButton+1] = widget.newButton{ 
        id = #levelButton,
        label = #levelButton,
        default = "images/levelButton.png",
        over = "images/levelButtonPressed.png",
        width = 50,
        height = 50,
        onRelease = levelSelected
    }

    levelButton[#levelButton].x = positionX;
    levelButton[#levelButton].y = positionY;
end
```

If it doesn't work, just check console and see if the loop is executed desired times.

Last edit:
Oh, didn't notice that. You never created levelButton table before! Before starting to create level buttons you should create that like this: local levelButton = {}, at outside of for loop

Comment: Well like I said in my question it seems to only iterate the loop once however I have a feeling that it's not due to the loop itself and instead hitting a problem during the loop which causes it to stop looping.

Comment: thats why I put a print function there. So you can check if loop completes or it gives an error inside and spots. If you can tell me what console prints, that would be great

Comment: Well if you check the updated code in my question you can see that I've got a 'print' function inside. The error the console is spitting out is at the bottom of the question.

Comment: Oh, didn't notice that. You never created levelButton table before! Before starting to create level buttons you should create that like this: local levelButton = {}, at outside of for loop

Comment: Ah ha! Bingo. Thanks thats what was needed! (I recommend adding that to the answer for others to find in the future!)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to reconsider your algorithm and change this while loop.

If the number of levels to be generated is going to stay constant you might want to do a for loop until the 31 st loop is reached.

```
 for i=1,levelstToBeMade  do

    levelstToBeMade = (levelsToBeMade - 1); -- Ignore numbers.
    positionX = positionX + 10; -- Ignore numbers.
    positionY = postionY + 10; -- Ignore numbers.

    levelButton[levelsToBeMade] = widget.newButton{ 
        id = levelsToBeMade,
        label = levelsToBeMade,
        default = "images/levelButton.png",
        over = "images/levelButtonPressed.png",
        width = 50,
        height = 50,
        onRelease = levelSelected
    }

    levelButton[levelsToBeMade].x = positionX;
    levelButton[levelsToBeMade].y = positionY;

 end
```

Hope this helps.

Cheers

Comment: Fair point, sadly that doesn't get around the original issue.

Answer (score 0):

(Sorry, I don't know Corona so this might not apply.)

What is `levelButton`, and are you sure it exists? Maybe it should be `levelButtons`?

If that's fine as it is, then check to make sure `newButton()` actually returns a table as expected: `print(levelButton[buttonNumber])`

Comment: Not sure where that spelling mistake was, however it's all sorted now.